# Why can't I iterate over my ArrayController when its in an outlet?

Tags: arrays, ember.js, controller

I have a page in my app where there are controls on the side that let you choose if you want to manage accounts or groups. I then have an outlet in my handlebars where I'll render the appropriate template for what the user wants to work on: `{{outlet workbench}}`.

This works fine for accounts:

```
  @render('account/link/workbench', {
    into   : 'account/link'
    outlet : 'workbench'
    controller : 'accountLink'
  })
```

But, for groups, it's somewhat broken:

```
  @render('account/link/groups', {
    into : 'account/link'
    outlet : 'workbench'
    controller : 'accountGroup'
  })
```

Both the `AccountLinkController` and `AccountGroupController` inherit from the same base class -- `TableController` -- which is an `ArrayController`. The problem is, I can't iterate over the child controllers in the `AccountGroupController`. (i.e. functions like `this.map` always return an empty array. I can iterate over the items in `AccountGroupController` using `{{#each}}` in the template) But, everything works fine from the `AccountLinkController`.

The only difference that I can think of between these two is that the page is setup by the `AccountLinkRoute` so there must be some Ember Magic setting up the `AccountLinkController` which is not happening with the `AccountGroupController`.

Any ideas where to go with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your on the right trail. The ember workflow is really important here. When you navigate to a URL Ember parses the URL and maps it to your router. At that point Ember knows it needs to fetch the models from each resource/route that are part of the URL. Once it's fetched all of those models it decorates them with the associated controllers. This right here describes where your issue is. Just using a controller doesn't cause a model to be fetched.

If you want to use a particular controller you can use `controllerFor` and manually obtain the model.

```
 // get some model
 var controller = this.controllerFor('accountGroup');
 controller.set('model', model);
 @render('account/link/groups', {
    into : 'account/link'
    outlet : 'workbench'
    controller : controller
  })
```

Comment: This looks like it's getting me in the right direction. One of the uglier parts of this controller (as well as `AccountLinkController` which is working as expected) is that the `content` is a computed property rather than a model that is wired in the route. So, I am getting the correct models in content -- I can iterate over them with `{{#each}}` in the template -- but I can't iterate over them using `@forEach()` from the controller.